# How do I get rid of the white outline around my button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get the white outline out of this button?

Here's the CSS, tell me if you think something caused it.

```
.btn {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(51, 197, 230, 0.5) 0%,rgba(51, 230, 131, 0.5) 50%,rgba(108,0,153,0.65) 100%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 1315px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 1s ease;
  transition: box-shadow 1s ease;
}

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-bob {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4px);
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-bob {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4px);
    transform: translateY(-4px);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hvr-bob-float {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-bob-float {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px);
    transform: translateY(-8px);
  }
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.btn:hover, a.btn:focus, a.btn:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-bob-float, hvr-bob;
  animation-name: hvr-bob-float, hvr-bob;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .3s, 1.5s;
  animation-duration: .3s, 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, .3s;
  animation-delay: 0s, .3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in-out;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out, ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 1, infinite;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal, alternate;
  animation-direction: normal, alternate;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `border:none;`?

Comment: Tried `outline:none`?

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle if you can.

Comment: `1315px` wide is a freakin' big button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above commenters are correct-- `border: none` and `outline: none` would be good starts.  Remember that the browser itself has some default styles-- if you want to override them before you start trying to style I'd recommend investigating a [CSS Reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/).  Also, is your `.btn` classed element a div, or a true `button`?  If the latter, remember native form elements are difficult to style appropriately cross browser, so if the visual treatment is important, you should consider using a `div` and an event handler.